# objective-c : iphone programming error with localization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, gps

i had a gps into my application that worked well for a time and now he is not working anymore and this is why it says in the console :

```
/SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-38/Runtime/PBRequester.m:660 server returned error: 503
```

Comment: I'm not sure what localisation has to do with this; it seems that `PBRequester` is trying to talk to a server but the server doesn't want to talk back or play nicely.

Comment: i didn't find the problem yet...

Comment: ok i tryed to run my last application with the same system and it doesnt work more so the problem is not in the code but something with a option or dunno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make the application? Or it's a third party app?

From the error message, it's using [Protocol Buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to communicate with the server, and the server returns error code 503. We may fairly suppose the app is using Protocol Buffer over HTTP and the error code of 503 means [Service Unavailable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) in HTTP world.

Comment: i have make the application it was working fine its just a gps